# Synchronization in java giving unexpected output

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I was going through a book and saw a code that says that below code is thread synchronized :

//Account class

```
 public class Account {

 private double balance;

 public double getBalance() {
 return balance;
}

 public void setBalance(double balance) {
 this.balance = balance;
}


 public synchronized void addAmount(double amount) {
 double tmp=balance;
 try {
 Thread.sleep(10);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
 tmp+=amount;
 balance=tmp;
}


public synchronized void subtractAmount(double amount) {
  double tmp=balance;
try {
Thread.sleep(10);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
tmp-=amount;
balance=tmp;
}

}
```

//Bank Class

```
public class Bank implements Runnable {

 private Account account;
 public Bank(Account account) {
  this.account=account; 
}

@Override

public void run() {

for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){

     account.subtractAmount(1000);
  }
 }
}
```

//Company class

```
public class Company implements Runnable {

 private Account account;

 public Company(Account account) {
    this.account=account;
}

@Override

 public void run() {
   for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
   account.addAmount(1000);
   }
  }
}
```

//Main class

```
 public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Account account=new Account();
 account.setBalance(1000);
 Company company=new Company(account);
 Thread companyThread=new Thread(company);
 Bank bank=new Bank(account);
 Thread bankThread=new Thread(bank);
 System.out.printf("Account : Initial Balance: %f\n",account.
 getBalance());
 companyThread.start();
 bankThread.start();

 try {
   companyThread.join();
   bankThread.join();
   System.out.printf("Account : Final Balance: %f\n",account.
   getBalance());
 } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Here two thread of two different object is changing the balance variable at the same time using addAmount and subtractAmount function , but it's always giving right output as Initial and Final balance same i.e 1000.000 . I mean their should me some problem as both thread is working on the same variable at the same time .

Please correct me where i am going wrong . 
Thank in advance

Comment: That's why you use `synchronized`

Comment: Actually, the book is not fully correct. You can set the balance not synchronized. Only add and subtract are. Can you tell us what book it is?

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole point of synchronized. It makes sure only one thread at a time can execute the function.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in Java is that each object has an intrisinc lock, and the use of the synchronize keyword indicates that when a Thread (let's call it A) calls that method, the thread A holds the lock. While the thread A holds the lock, other threads will be blocked from accessing the synchronized section of the Object (in your case the Account object).

Once Thread A has finished executing the synchronized block (or method in this case), Thread A releases the lock on the object, and other threads waiting to access your Account object can now proceed forward.

> - First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing
>     a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke
>     synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution)
>     until the first thread is done with the object.
> - Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent
>     invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This
>     guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all
>     threads.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html for more détails on the use of synchronized.

Actually to make Account thread safe, you would want to have the setter synchronized and the balance being declared as volatile :

```
public class Account {

 private volatile double balance;

 public double getBalance() {
 return balance;
 }

 public synchronized void setBalance(double balance) {
 this.balance = balance;
}
```

//rest of code is already synchronized
   }

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html for more on the volatile use.